# unable to load @font_face in my wamp localhost?

Tags: css

I am trying to add some custom font in my site but unable to do. I am not sure if I am using a right or wrong path. Kindly help.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: XfinityStandard
  src: url('landingpage/fonts/XfinityStandard-Light.woff2') format("woff2");
```

where `landingpage` is folder name.

Comment: Semicolon and closing brace are missed. See [font-face](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) rule.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to check:

1. Is the font actually working (i.e. can you see it rendering properly), and
2. Inspect your page (e.g. in Chrome, right-click the text you expect the font to render on, and select `Inspect` from the drop-down menu.  In your `Styles` tab, at the right-hand bottom of the page, there should be a section called `Rendered Fonts`.  If you have implemented your font correctly, it should show here (in addition to the css hierarchy applied, where your font should be listed).

If your font is not showing here, make sure you follow the following:

1. The `@font-face` rule should be added to your css before any styles
2. Use your rule in your css by specifying the font as `XfinityStandard` and provide a fall-back like `sans-serif`, e.g. `body { font-family: 'XfinityStandard', sans-serif; }`
3. Make sure you have wide support, so when you specify your font, add an additional source for `format('woff')`
4. As Devansh J mentioned, make sure your font is relative to the css file
5. If you are still having issues, maybe consider a hosted font like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), as follows: `@import url(///fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat` which you can use as `body { font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }`